# Program returning previous information instead of new information

Tags: java, postgresql, arraylist, jdbc

I am implementing a menu-driven program where the user can search for books based on different options such as:  ISBN, Title and etc. The problem I am having is that if the user chooses the same option twice it will return the same seller and price from the previous run.

For example, if the user chooses option 1, and enter the isbn 18937646282. It is suppose to return the following: `seller: adrake Price: 20.56`. Then, the user chooses option 1 again, and enter the isbn: 87473626262. It is supposed to return the following: seller: `aharrison Price 10:20`. However, it returns the same thing as the first run which is: `seller: adrake Price: 20.56`.

The program works correctly if I exit the program and rerun the entire program. Also, I have printed out the isbn and it is retrieving the correct isbn, author, title for each run. It is just not retrieving the correct seller and price. Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated. The code below shows option1():

```
List<BookSale> booklist = new ArrayList<>();
public void option1() throws SQLException, IOException
   {
      String sql;
      String sql_;
      String sql_info;
      int option;
      int i;
      int count = 0;


      // asks user to enter ISBN 
      System.out.print("Enter ISBN of the book you are searching for: ");
      isbn = stdin.next();

       //sql statement to select seller and price for user desired ISBN
       sql_ = "SELECT *" + " from BOOK_SALE " + "WHERE isbn = " +
            "'" + isbn + "'" + "and status =" + "'active'";

      // execute query
      result2 = select.executeQuery(sql_);

      // display Seller and Price of the desired ISBN, add book to ArrayList
      while(result2.next())
      {
         BookSale book = new BookSale(listing_no, seller,isbn, condition,price);
         book.setListingNumber(result2.getInt(1));
         book.setSeller(result2.getString(2));
         book.setISBN(result2.getString(3));
         book.setCondition(result2.getString(4));
         book.setPrice(result2.getDouble(5));
         booklist.add(book);
         count++;
      } // while

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) //0
         {
            // display number of the selections
            System.out.println(i + " " + booklist.get(i));
         }// for
```

The function to print out seller and price in the class:

```
@Override
      public String toString(){
         return ". Seller:" + seller + " Price: $" + price;
         }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You really should not concatenate values into a query string, that is unsafe and a big security bug. Please learn about prepared statement and parameters.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi Mark, That is my next step! I am shaky on how prepared statements work, so I wanted to be able to get the the program working correctly first.